# How to show product custom attribute value on sales order view page under magento admin

Tags: magento2.2.6

How to show product custom attribute value on sales order view page under magento 2.2.6 admin.

Comment: You will need to get Product Id from Order object then load product from ID.
Finally you can get Attribute from Product Object.

Comment: Whenever I try to get product attribute from product object it shows always default value not selected.

Comment: To get Selected value you need to get  all option's of attribute and then match option value from order item option.

Comment: It will be better if you can send me any example